# Huge list in Python returning None elements

Tags: python, list, file, csv, size

I've a CSV file like:

```
134;football
1457;soccer
12;volley
...
```

It has 4.992.909 lines exactly. The code is:

```
with open('/Users/someone/Desktop/python/sports.csv', 'r') as file1:        
    f = set(file1)

sports_label_list = [None] * 9985818

i = 0

for line in f:
    sports = line.split(';')[0]
    sports_label_list[i] = sports
    i = i + 1
    if 'football' in line:
        sports_label_list[i] = 'football'
    if 'volley' in line:
        sports_label_list[i] = 'volley'
    if 'basketball' in line:
        sports_label_list[i] = 'basketball'
    if 'soccer' in line:
        sports_label_list[i] = 'soccer'
    i = i + 1
```

When I do print to check sports_label_list, it goes OK (showing numeric values at even numbers and sports names at odd numbers) until somewhere near the 30000 element of the list. After that, it starts to print 'None'. The CSV file is ok. Any suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: The file probably has duplicate lines, which `set` eliminates. Why are you putting it in a set? Needless use of memory.

Comment: Why aren't you using `list.append()`?

Comment: The duplicate lines are important.

Answer (score 0):

The file probably has duplicate lines, which set eliminates. Why are you putting it in a set? Needless use of memory. A better, and faster choice would be to build up the list incrementally:

```
sports_label_list = []

with open('/Users/someone/Desktop/python/sports.csv', 'r') as file1:   
    for line in file1:
        number, sport = line.strip().split(";")
        sport_label_list.append(number)
        if sport in ("football", "soccer", "baseball", "basketball"):
            sport_label_list.append(sport)
        else:
            sport_label_list.append(None)
```

Comment: Nice! But one more question: it's returning from the same line? I'm checking but not sure if the list = ['1457', 'soccer, '134', 'football', ...] because it needs to be.

Comment: It's okay! Thank you

Comment: No problem. If this solved your problem, you can accept my answer.